# angularjs repeat does not show data at first time

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, webmethod

First, I am so sorry because of my English.
I am showing a table that it's data come from server and shown with angular repeat.
I make a ng-click on each row of table that send an ajax request and get another list that I want to show in another table, until now all the thing are right,
but I have a little problem, my problem is that I must click twice on my first table's row to show second table data, at first time all the data comes from server but did not show in second table, my angular  code is shown below.

```
 angular.module("BI", [])
       .controller("ListTables", function ($scope, $http) {
           $scope.ReportLst = [];
           $scope.myData = {};
           $scope.myData.ReportLst = [];
           $scope.myData.ReportDetail = [];
           $scope.myData.ReportDetail2 = [];
           $scope.selectedReportval = "";
           $scope.Load = function () {
               $http.post('MakeReport.aspx/LoadReportLst', { data: {} })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.myData.ReportLst = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status) {
                       alert('error');
                   });

           }
           $scope.SelectRepID = function (val) {

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "MakeReport.aspx/GetReportDetail",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   data: "{ 'val': '" + val + "'}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (data) {
                       $scope.myData.ReportDetail = JSON.parse(data.d);
                   },
                   error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                       alert(data.d);
                   }
               });
               $scope.selectedReportval = val;
           }
       });
```

Comment: can you update your html code ?

Answer (score 1):

In your second request you're using `$.ajax` instead of `$http`, because this isn't an Angular function a [`digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) won't be triggered and your view won't be updated, in order to fix this you have to use `$http` there too.

```
$scope.SelectRepID = function (val) {
    $http.post({
        url: "MakeReport.aspx/GetReportDetail",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ 'val': '" + val + "'}",
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(
        function(data) {
            $scope.myData.ReportDetail = JSON.parse(data.d);
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    );
    $scope.selectedReportval = val;
}
```

---

Update: Another way would be to use a `$timeout` in your `$.ajax` success function like so (this will trigger a digest).

```
success: function (data) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.myData.ReportDetail = JSON.parse(data.d);
    });
}
```

Comment: @SourabhAgrawal Updated my answer, using $timeout is a better way

Comment: I have problem in sendig data to my webmethod when using $http.post

Comment: Then wrap your $.ajax success call in a `$timeout()` (this is not 'the angular way' though)

Comment: this is my error when sendig data to server Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data